# Как заполнить форму начальными данными?

Tags: python, django

помогите пожалуйста при первой загрузке формы вывести в полях формы данные из базы данных .

models:

```
class Status(models.Model):     
    status = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=False, )     
    @classmethod
    def get_status_list(self):
        status_list = list()
        status_list.append(('', 'Не указан'))
        for values_ins in Status.objects.all().values_list('id', 'status'):
            status_list.append(values_ins)
        return status_list

class UserProfile(User):            
    name1 = models.CharField('Имя', max_length=30,  blank=True, null=True,  )
    name2 = models.CharField('Отчество',    max_length=30,  blank=True, null=True,  )
    status = models.ForeignKey(Status,  verbose_name='Статус',  blank=True, null=True,  )
```

forms:

```
class PersonalDataForm(forms.ModelForm):
    status = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select, choices=Status.get_status_list(),label='Статус',required=False, )       
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('name1', 'name2', )
```

views:

```
@login_required
def personal_data_page(request):
    entry_user_profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user_ptr_id=request.user.id)
    form = PersonalDataForm(instance=entry_user_profile)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PersonalDataForm(request.POST, instance=entry_user_profile)
        if form.is_valid():         
            form.save() 
            entry_user_profile.save()   
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/userprofile/personal_data_page_changed/')

    t = loader.get_template('personal_data_page.html')
    c = RequestContext(request, {'form': form,})
    return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
```

template:

```
{{ form.name1 }}
{{ form.name2 }}
{{ form.status }}
```

проблема в том, что при первой загрузке формы пользователь видит данные из базы данных в полях: "name1", "name2". но не видит данные из базы данных в поле "status"(там показывается пункт "не указан", хотя должен показываться пункт, соответсвтующий значению в поле status_id таблицы UserProfile)

мне нужно чтобы при первой загрузке формы в поле "status" было указано определённое значение. помогите пожалуйста

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выкинте метод get_status_list.

В форме:

```
status = UserProfile._meta.get_field('status').formfield(empty_label=u'Не указан', required=False)
```

Таким образом вы получите реальное поле status формы, которое заполнится инициализационными данными.

Answer (score 0):

Эммм, а почему у вас в форме поле status описано вручную, еще и с костылями? Если у вас что-то не получается - не стоит сразу городить подпорки, лучше разобраться, все ли вы правильно поняли и действительно ли штатными средствами это не делается, потом поискать готовое решение, и только если готовых решений нет или они совсем не подходят, строить свое.